# Chainlink job not working with external bridge, it is giving an error "Error: UnprocessableEntityError"

Tags: go-ethereum, chainlink

I have created an external adapter and hosted it on AWS server as it required to get data from third part URL with authentication headers.
I have also hosted a chainlink node and added this AWS resource as a bridge on the node and also have hosted a oracle contract on rinkyby at 0xe0c225707052ab8e2F584220eFC7fA8E0b1DF7b7.

Now as per the documentation, I need to add a new job with v2 spec (TOML) format. I tried it using the following code

```
type                = "directrequest"
schemaVersion       = 1
name                = "TwitterUsernameVerification"
contractAddress     = "0xe0c225707052ab8e2F584220eFC7fA8E0b1DF7b7"
externalJobID       = "0EEC7E1D-D0D2-476C-A1A8-72DFB6633F47"
observationSource   = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]
    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse 
                              data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    bridge_fetch  [type=bridge 
                             name=twitter-username-verification 
                            requestData=<{
                                    "twitter_username": "$(decode_cbor.twitter_username)",
                                    "address": "$(decode_cbor.address)"
                           }>]
    parse    [type=jsonparse data="$(bridge_fetch)" path="data,result"]
    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(uint256 value)" data=<{ "value": $(parse) }>]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data=<{
                      "requestId": $(decode_log.requestId),
                      "payment": $(decode_log.payment),
                      "callbackAddress": $(decode_log.callbackAddr),
                      "callbackFunctionId": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId),
                      "expiration": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration),
                      "data": $(encode_data)
                  }>]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0xe0c225707052ab8e2F584220eFC7fA8E0b1DF7b7" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> bridge_fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

but it isnt working and giving me "Error: UnprocessableEntityError". When I checked the logs of this chainlink node, it is giving me following error

```
} clientIP=171.79.44.11 errors=Error #01: failed to parse V2 job TOML. HINT: If you are trying to add a V1 job spec (json) via the CLI, try `job_specs create` instead: (6, 1): unmarshal text: could not unmarshal DOT into a pipeline.Graph: Error in S82: INVALID(0,-u), Pos(offset=529, line=9, column=42), expected one of: ; ] , id 
Error #02: unknown job type: 
Error #03: (6, 1): unmarshal text: could not unmarshal DOT into a pipeline.Graph: Error in S82: INVALID(0,-u), Pos(offset=529, line=9, column=42), expected one of: ; ] , id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around your bridge name

```
name="twitter-username-verification"
```